# Make my app the default for NFC payments (android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, nfc

I'm looking for a way to check if my app is the default option in Tap & Pay and, if the user choses to, make it the default.
My app is developed in Ionic, but i think that for this i will need to make a java/kotlin plugin.
I've been looking for a few days and didn't came across any idea for this.
Thank you!